# Please reconsider “Mac OS spell checking” question for reopening

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, reopen-request

The question [How to Improve Mac OS Spell Checking?](https://superuser.com/q/1016525/150988)<sup>1</sup>
was downvoted and (rightfully) closed as a product request. 
It was then edited to make it a solution request rather than a product request. 
Apparently the edit injected it [into the Reopen Vote Queue](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/481164),
where it got three **Reopen** votes (one of them was from me,
and another was from one of the users who voted to close)
and no **Leave Closed** votes.

Unfortunately, the OP doesn’t have the privilege of seeing close/reopen votes,
and, believing that the question had simply been rejected by the community,
deleted it.  At my urging, he has now undeleted it;
unfortunately, it has not been restored to an active state in the Reopen Queue
(“This item is no longer reviewable.”)  3K+ users,
please look at this question, judge whether it is worthy of reopening,
and, if you agree that it is, please vote accordingly.
______
<sup>1</sup> (originally titled [Is there a better library/third-party-software
spell-checker for Mac that can guess accurate spellings](https://superuser.com/revisions/1016525/1))

<sup>(I do not know the OP or have any vested interested
in reopening the question.)</sup>

Comment: 1 more vote required ;)

Comment: Hmmm....would this type of question be better served in the Apple SE?

Comment: Bumped by the Community bot.  I think if you accept the answer, that will prevent it from popping up again.

Comment: @fixer1234: OK, done. (Too bad the original question still hasn't gotten an answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this time, it's been re-opened.